# Facebook Graph API Group Posts Not Showing Link Preview / Picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a Facebook application that successfully posts to Facebook pages, and creates the link preview with the photo successfully.

However, when posting to Groups, often the post only contains the message parameter, and does not successfully create a link preview.

I've also seen this happen with Hootsuite--all the posts to the Facebook Pages are correct, but the post to the Facebook Groups sometimes contain no link preview / picture.

Is there some undocumented Facebook functionality that is causing this to happen? I have posted some pictures with this question as well showing what I mean.

[image: Working Picture]

^ Here is the application posting as a Page

[image: Not workig picture]

^ Here is the application posting as a Group, 80% of the time. (Other 20%, the link preview works correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

There's limited support for posting to / reading from Groups via the API - as far as I know it does not work the same way for groups as it does for pages or user profiles, which leads to the discrepancy above - I don't think there's any other API available to make it work the way you're looking for

Comment: Well, the odd thing is that 20% of the time it works properly, as listed above. I was even testing, and posted to the group using my client's token and the link preview didn't work correctly, and then switched the token to my own and posted to a group that I was a member of using the same code and it went through without a problem. Which leads me to believe that it is linked to the tokens, or there is something buggy/undocumented in the Facebook API. You should be able to use the feed API the same way as the Page API though.